# Insert using Union/Union All fails to insert all rows

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am trying to insert the result of a UNION into a table .While I cannot reproduce the original query here, due to it being in a restricted environment, it's structure looks similar to this:

```
WITH temp(X,Y,Z) AS(
SELECT....
)
SELECT X,Y,Z from TEMP --PART A
UNION 
SELECT 'A','B','C' FROM DUAL;--PART B
```

Part A of the query returns about 1000 records, while Part B is just a single record.

When I wrap this whole query inside a procedure, such that the result of the select statements are inserted into a table, I see that only Part B, a single record gets inserted into the target table.Here is what it loos like when I wrap it inside the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(COLUMN1,COLUMN2....)
 WITH temp(X,Y,Z) AS(
    SELECT....
    )
    SELECT X,Y,Z from TEMP
    UNION 
    SELECT 'A','B','C' FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
END;
```

I tried using both UNION and UNION ALL, but somehow I don't see to get the Part A of the result set inserted into the table.

What could be the possible reasons for such a scenario to occur? I tried to replicate the same ,but failed.

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you wrap the query inside your procedure. Is it a single `insert ... with ... select`, or you make it a cursor and do row-by-row-inserts, or using bulk collections? Are there filters that use literals when you run it standalone and variables/arguments in the procedure - which could indicate a name or data type mismatch? There isn't really anything to go on at the moment. A [mcve] would be helpful - if you can't replicate it, it's hard for us to understand or replicate it too...

Comment: Obviously from your description that Part A doesn't return rows. If it works in SQL, but doesn't in a PL/SQL procedure, you need to check if your query still the same as in SQL. You can get your real query text from 10046 trace or in v$open_cursor/v$sql. For example you may have aliases or columns with the same name as a variable in your procedure.

Comment: @AlexPoole,edited y question to include how the procedure looks like. With regards to minimal reproducible example, I am unable to replicate this by myself, using similar queries that involves WITH and the UNION clauses.

Comment: No arguments or changes to the query at all? What happens if you run the insert standalone? (As the procedure wrapper doesn't seem to be adding anything at the moment). There's no reason CTE or union would be an issue with what you're shown. The CTE query could still be referencing something that evaluates differently, maybe based on roles - or lack of roles as it seems to be a definer's rights procedure. We can only guess though; you'll need to debug the procedure.

Comment: @AlexPoole ,Running the INSERT standalone produces the same result->Part B (1 row) gets inserted.

Comment: @AlexPoole I can assure you that this is not because of any issue with the roles/rights, because the same 'user/role' applies to similar tables/procedures, and they just seem to work fine .In other words, similar objects created by the same users work correctly. There is no explicit grant/revocation of any rights/privileges whatsoever.

Comment: If literally all you do is add the `insert` line then maybe you're hitting a bug. You've tagged two versions; which version and patch level of Oracle are you actually using? You could also try a workaround of turning the CTE into an inline view, since you only reference it once anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole,I use 11g,not 12C. I will anyways try out the cursor method below and see if I get to insert all the rows at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR CUR IS SELECT X, Y, Z FROM OG_TABLE UNION SELECT 'A', 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL;
BEGIN 
  
  FOR REC IN CUR 
    LOOP 
    
    INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (REC.X, REC.Y, REC.Z);
    
  END LOOP;
  
END;
```

Alternative Optimized code

```
DECLARE 
  LIM PLS_INTEGER := 100;

  CURSOR CUR IS SELECT X, Y, Z FROM OG_TABLE UNION SELECT 'A', 'B', 'C' 
  FROM DUAL;
 
  TYPE OG_REC IS RECORD( X OG_TABLE.X%TYPE, Y OG_TABLE.Y%TYPE, Z 
  OG_TABLE%TYPE);

  TYPE OGT IS TABLE OF OG_REC;
  OG_TAB OGT;

BEGIN 
  
  OPEN CUR;
   
  LOOP
    
    FETCH CUR BULK COLLECT INTO OG_TAB LIMIT LIM;
    
        BEGIN
     
             FORALL i IN 1..OG_TAB.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
             INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (OG_TAB(i).X, 
             OG_TAB(i).Y, OG_TAB(i).Z);
    
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
        END;
    
  EXIT WHEN CUR%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  
  COMMIT;
  CLOSE CUR;
END;
```

Comment: A single insert would be more efficient than looping and doing 1000+ individual inserts. This may be what the OP is already doing, but even if not, I don't think this will help resolve whatever is causing the first branch of the union to not find any rows.

Comment: What about implicit optimisation oracle does? If that’s not the case then yes it is not efficient, It will better to bulk collect and use FORALL to insert data.

Comment: If Oracle doesn’t optimise Cursor For Loop implicitly then I really learned something wrong.

Comment: [It doesn't](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/slow-by-slow.html). And yes `FORALL` would be an improvement, but still slower than a single `insert ... `select`, as well as needing more memory to hold the collection.